# magento all subcategories including name link and image

Tags: php, magento

currently i have a subcategory page that shows the correct names, pulls the right links and displays everything in an orderly maner.

However, i have come upon a peculiar problem, as the images are all the same picture pulled from one of the categories. this should of course be the image related to the category name, can anyone spot where i have made a mistake?

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 465;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)   ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>

                <ul class="catblocks">
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>" />
                            <span><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></span></a>
                            <?php $_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                            <?php if($_category2->hasChildren()):?>
                            <?php $_subcategories2 = $_category2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

any help is apreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    //gets all sub categories of parent category
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(6)->getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
        $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
            'url' => $category->getUrl(),
            'img' => $category->getImageUrl()
        );
    }

    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: this wont work as it pulls products out of the subcategories, i need a list of categories and subcategories which is why im pulling out the getChildrenCategories.

Comment: Hi follow this link- https://docs.google.com/document/d/11HVebprhUq99sHO5sJmFeACdSH66JpCyVqVIY7q9Inc/edit

Comment: with abit of restructuring i made your solution work :) thanks a lot